# Cannot access network from Docker container

Tags: linux, docker, networking

The gist of the issue is that if I create and run a docker container (from any image, I tried many) **the container does not have network access** beyond the default bridge Docker creates; even when using IP addresses (not URLs/names).

I.e.

- `docker run --rm -it busybox ping 8.8.8.8` hangs/fails for not having accessing the network
- `docker run --rm -it busybox ping 172.17.0.1` also fails (note that `172.17.0.1` is `docker0`'s IP on the host and also the gateway set by docker in the container)
- if I create two containers I can ping either one from the other fine

N.B:

1. I have two Ubuntu hosts (same version) both running Docker 19.03.6.  On one of them (dev machine) I don't have the issue (it works just fine), on the other one I do.  Which means it is most likely not an OS and/or Docker version issue but some sort of misconfiguration.
2. It is **not** the DNS issue asked in most questions I could find.  In fact, it is not a DNS issue at all.  It presents itself when I use direct IP addresses as well as with URLs.

I use `iptables` on the host; these are the rules on the one where it does not work (they are different on the dev machine where networking works fine but I cannot set the here the same):

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
f2b-postfix-sasl  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports smtp,urd,submission,imap3,imaps,pop3,pop3s
f2b-sshd   tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports ssh
fail2ban-ssh  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports ssh
fail2ban-ssh  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports ssh
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp echo-request
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp spt:ntp state ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:imap2 state NEW,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:imaps state NEW,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:urd state NEW,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:urd state NEW,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:submission state NEW,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:smtp state NEW,ESTABLISHED

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER-USER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:ntp state NEW,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:imap2 state ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:imaps state ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:urd state ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:smtp state ESTABLISHED

Chain DOCKER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain f2b-postfix-sasl (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain f2b-sshd (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain fail2ban-ssh (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

I am not sure what else to add for clarification.

What should I do?

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is for programming questions and not general computing issues. Please review [What topics can I ask here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more details. Question may be appropriate for [Super User](http://superuser.com) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) but do check their help before posting.

Comment: you have iptables chain `DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2` specifying DROP all anywhere

Comment: @kaylum: Fair enough I posted out of routine.  I'll repost it over at Super User.

Comment: @akazuko: Thanks for the find.  I'll try to remove it by hand and see what happens.  However, this is automatically inserted by Docker.  (I tried to stop the docker daemon, remove all docker-related rules by hand and restarting docker and these are the rules after that.)  Do you have some pointers to review/edit rules docker creates (and why)?  

Also, I have the same rule in the dev machine and there it works fine.  But it has given me an idea: I'll move the rules from the failing box to the working one one (block) at a time and see which one kills the network...  If it's that at all.